# gremlin .mergeE / .mergeV in javascript/typescript example

Tags: javascript, typescript, merge, gremlin, amazon-neptune

all examples for mergeV/mergeE seem to be groovy but it's not obvious how to translate them to javascript.
I got as far as this:

```
const { onCreate, onMatch } = gremlin.process.merge;
const { from_, to } = gremlin.process.direction;

this
  .mergeE(to, tgt.id)
  .option(onCreate, { created: now, updated: now })
  .option(onMatch, { updated: now })
```

but the mergeE instruction generates an error.

I tried:

1. `.mergeE([to, tgt.id])` with the effect: "Could not locate exact method given the supplied arguments: NeptuneGraphTraversal.mergeE(ArrayList)"
2. `.mergeE(to, tgt.id)` Could not locate exact method given the supplied arguments
3. `.mergeE({ [to.toString()]: tgt.id, [from_.toString()]: this.id })` an unexpected error has occured in Neptune; obviously we cannot do [to]: tgt.id in js

If anyone has a clear example for mergeE in javascript/typescript, it would help immensely. I'm asking specifically in the Amazon Neptune context but hopefully it can be useful for other cases as well.
Even better would be to have a side-by side example for mergeV, but maybe a lot to ask.

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.gremlator.com/ for doing these translations?

(I am the author of this site, so if it is missing a feature that you need here, please let me know)

Comment: while it helps to know that (maybe) a groovy map is mapped by new Map() in js, translating this g.mergeE([(from): 'v-1', (to): 'v-2', (T.label): 'KNOWS']) to this: g.mergeE(new Map([[Direction.OUT,"v-1"],[Direction.IN,"v-2"],[T.label,"KNOWS"]]))  raises questions such as: why Direction.OUT and not .from, how can I select the node first and then merge etc. Moreover the query as given by your tool gets stuck until neptune times out.

Comment: I am not sure what you are seeing, as this translation works on Neptune when I try it.```const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const direction = gremlin.process.direction
const t = gremlin.process.t

const g = traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('wss://XXX:8182/gremlin'));
 g.mergeE(new Map([[direction.out,"v-1"],[direction.in,"v-2"],[t.label,"KNOWS"]])).toList().then(data => console.log(data))```

Comment: Regarding the choice of IN and OUT versus FROM and TO.  FROM and TO are just friendly aliases to IN and OUT as seen here: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/a68b404f93c4b53cb102986b39115fe0ab54d94e/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib/process/traversal.js#L476

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example translation of what I believe you are trying to accomplish:

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const direction = gremlin.process.direction
const t = gremlin.process.t
const { onCreate, onMatch } = gremlin.process.merge;

const g = traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('wss://<CLUSTER ENDPOINT>:8182/gremlin'));

g.
mergeE(new Map([[t.label,"Test"],
[direction.out,'1'],[direction.in,'2']])).
option(onCreate,new Map([["created",Date.now()]])).
option(onMatch,new Map([["updated",Date.now()]])).elementMap().toList().then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm assuming your code is correct, but unfortunately it times out. Maybe amazon specific, will take it to the neptune forum. Should there be a way to do g(id).mergeE(...) and specify only .in or .out, and on the opposite side, should we be able to chain more steps to it, like .property(...)?

Comment: I tested this on a Neptune cluster, so if you are getting a timeout error, then something else is likely the culprit there.  Can you run any queries from this machine to your cluster?  e.g. `g.V().limit(1)`

Comment: yes the cluster is fine, all old queries work. I figured the engine was outdated (it's just a few weeks old but the merge updates are very recent). Updated the cluster engine + gremlin console, now merge works from gremlin console. But from typescript the query still times out. Will update when I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

@bechbd 's answer works as expected, but my journey to resolve this took a few extra steps which I believe are worth listing. I had to:

- make sure Neptune is at the latest engine version
- make sure the gremlin and gremlin-aws-sigv4 libraries are at their latest versions (not sure sig4 update was *necessary* but it didn't hurt). In typescript, also remember to update @types/gremlin

At this stage the example from the accepted answer would work verbatim. However the mergeE construct still wouldn't work for me in the context of an existing project (the query was getting stuck). Checking the connection configuration I found "mimeType: 'application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json'" and other headers being added to the connection, probably a requirement by older engine versions. While there may be a better header *removing all headers resolved the issue* for my case.
So in the context of a framework/project check up the connection chain, this may help save some time.

The time-wise performance improvement I've gained from moving to mergeE is between x16 and x60 based on a (not so) edge case where there are 100k edges with the same label that should be checked to ensure idempotency. I guess the original query could have been improved but this is the point of merge statements, to leave the optimization to the engine.

Finally a couple of links that go beyond the formal explanation in the official gremlin doc:

- https://gist.github.com/spmallette/5cd448f38d5dae832c67d890b576df31
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-efficient-upserts.html

Thanks @bechbd for the help and the community for pushing for a better gremlin.